# Do I create a custom theme or modify css in a genesis child theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis

I've just got started with Wordpress and it was suggested to use a child theme so I purchased the Magazine Pro theme. This has got the perfect layout for my needs but I find some of the padding is too intense and in particular when I have a leaderboard banner at the top my text for my blog title is wrapping.

I want to reduce my title text and reduce the padding. I know how to do that, I've got plenty of experience in front end dev but I just don't know if I should create a child theme (or grandchild theme) based off Magazine Pro or whether I should modify the css file directly in my Magazine Pro css file? What I'm worried about it overwriting my changes by any updates to the child theme.

What's the best course of action here, I'm really keen to get cracking on some content but my site looks a bit crap with the header text wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you keep the original and create a child. This way if you make some mistakes you can then take the original code and correct them.

Comment: I could use Git for that and just revert the changes. I'm more concerned if the child theme upgrades or something. Is creating a child from the original a simple case of copy paste of the folder and renaming?

Comment: I think this might answer your question: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: "The problem is that modifying a theme even slightly prevents you from updating it to a newer version in the future, because if you do try to update, you lose all your changes.

Child themes solve this by allowing you to use all of the functionality of your chosen theme while allowing you to update it without the fear of losing your modifications." as per http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/?dsh=1&utm_expid=3606929-40.lszTaIEzTbifDhvhVdd39A.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ee%2F

Comment: M - I understand why to use child themes. I'm just wondering if this applies to a Genesis Framework child theme. Essentially I'll be creating a grandchild theme. Is that the correct way to go?

Comment: It does apply, in fact it looks like editing a child theme is required so you don't lose your changes when Genesis updates: https://www.nutsandboltsmedia.com/things-you-should-know-before-you-purchase-the-genesis-framework/